# Can I use an old-work box on an exterior wall?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, old-work

I would like to add an outlet to my deck -- there is no power there and running an extension cord around the house to another exterior outlet is a total bummer. I actually have relatively convenient access to run the wire right now so I'm not worries about that, but I don't know if adding an exterior outlet requires any special tools or processes -- I'd like to just cut a rectangular hole and use an old work box. Do I need to do anything special, or can I just grab any regular old work box (as long as I use a water tight face plate like you'd see on any other exterior outlet)

Edit: Per comments

- there is a GFCI in the utility room that all outdoor outlets are tied to
- This will be under the eaves of the roof, but about 6-8 feet below so it will still be vulnerably to driving rain
- The house a concrete siding (I'll position the outlet so that it's not over a seam in the siding)

Comment: It will need GFCI protection.  A GFCI lasts longer if it is inside of the house, than using a GFCI receptacle/outlet on the outside.  Not sure but newer code might want an in use weather cover rather than just a weather tight cover.

Comment: You could just drill a hole and have an exterior box face mounted. It's a little easier to seal up, but a little more obtrusive...

Comment: You *can* but it neither facilitates replacement nor longevity. Also doesn't leave you a side tap for putting a light later. And it's a pita to put a gfci in an OW box. - Under an overhang, I guess. But not anywhere it will *ever* see water (water tight my ass). Every OW box I've had to deal with outside is a rusty pos. The ext aluminum ones deteriorate also, but you take it off, toss it, and put a new one with two giant screws... not 3 out of 4, crappily, in an OW box, and now only two of which actually hold well if you're lucky.

Comment: What kind of wall are we talking here?  Siding?  Stucco?  Brick?

Comment: @Huesmann It's concrete fiberboard siding, I've updated the original question with additional details

Answer (score 8):

**Yes** you can mount an outside outlet on an old-work box cut into the wall.

Here are some tips:

- You can buy an outside outlet kit that includes a GFCI outlet, a wet-in-use cover and a foam gasket.  This can be mounted on an old-work, new-work, or exterior surface-mount box.
- Some people like to put the GFCI outlet *inside* the house, somewhere useful like the basement, then run a cable to the outside.  The idea is that the elements will destroy the outside outlet relatively quickly, and a regular outlet is cheaper to replace.   Well most new GFCI outlets have self-enforced shelf life anyway, they kill themselves before they get a chance to rust away.  So it's not that big a deal.
- If the wall isn't fairly smooth and flat, and most walls aren't, the foam gasket that comes with the cover isn't enough.  Plan to add some silicone to seal it to the box.
- Don't use a plastic wet-in-use box in an exposed location.  They *always* get broken.  Use them near inside corners, overhangs, behind furniture, etc where they won't get bumped by lawn mowers, children, balls, etc.  Otherwise use a metal cover that protrudes less.
- Before choosing an old-work box, look at the wall construction.  The box needs to be rock solid when mounted to handle the abuse it will take.  If you have vinyl siding you need to cut the box underneath it so the mounting won't be squishy.  If you have a stucco wall, forget about it.  Etc.  Make sure you'll be able to do a solid job.
- A surface-mounted exterior box solves most of these problems especially if you can screw it to a stud but it will protrude *even more* from the wall so you really need to think about placement so the plastic cover doesn't get smashed.

Comment: "Some people like to put the GFCI outlet inside the house" - Yes, 100%! Additionally, use a weather-rated (WR) outlet outdoors, even if it's covered by an overhang.

Comment: Also, from previous experience, using a surface-mount box with wires coming in through the back knockout is much better for thermal insulation (and easier to install) than any flush-mount box. And if you change your mind and want to move the outlet later, it's leaves less of a scar.